Which part of the C++ standard forbids double destruction and reusing storage without destroying?
Which parts of a modern C++ standard (C++20 or C++23 are fine) say that it's not okay to do the following things using placement new and explicit destructor calls?

Double destructor call
alignas(T) std::byte storage[sizeof(T)];
T* const p = new (storage) T(...);
p->~T();
p->~T();


Reuse storage without running destructor
alignas(T) std::byte storage[sizeof(T)];
T* p = new (storage) T(...);
p = new (storage) T(...)
p->~T();



Moreover, are these allowed if T has a trivial destructor, and which additional parts of the standard are relevant to that question?

I found this previous answer to a semi-related question that gives a relatively clear answer the the trivial destructor part of the question for (1), but it uses C++17 and to my surprise the wording in C++20 seems to have changed to also forbid this for trivial destructors. This seems like it should be fine for trivial destructors, so I suspect I'm missing something.

Three (!!) questions in one question. :/

Yes you're right, these should have been separate questions. I've posted them here and here and will vote to close this one. Sorry about that.

Tbh I'd rather keep it as is at this point. But ok, let me split up the answer, I guess?

@jacobsa You can go ahead and delete this question now that you've split it up into new separate questions.
